# How to get windows 7 to remember connected devices on a network

Tags: windows-7, networking

Is it possible to get Windows 7 to remember devices (e.g. computers) that have connected to a wireless / wired network even when they are offline in a kind of "Offline" section?

3rd party program suggestions are fine if this functionality is not built into Windows directly.

Comment: What kind of "Devices"?

Comment: Sorry - I meant computers, updating question.

Comment: What would be the point of this (as you won't be able to access them)?  Like, what are you actually trying to accomplish?  Have you looked into Windows' [Offline Files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/understanding-offline-files)?

Comment: @techie007 I just wanted to know which devices had connected to my network at some point in time.